# Jenkins workflow remote loader error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to import a remote script through the remote loader plugin for Jenkins worklow. I'm getting some weird error. When I put the exact code from that script in my main workflow script it works without issues.

I've also tried loading the example hello world script from the plugin's github, which works without issues.

Here's the remote script:

```
import org.rundeck.api.*
import org.rundeck.api.domain.*

import static org.rundeck.api.domain.RundeckExecution.ExecutionStatus.*

def version = '1.0'

def runJob(String jobId, Properties options) {
    RundeckClient rundeck = RundeckClient.builder().url("url").login("user", "password").version(11).build();
    RundeckExecution execution = rundeck.triggerJob(RunJobBuilder.builder().setOptions(options).setJobId(jobId).build());

    while (RUNNING.equals(execution.status)) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            break;
        }
        execution = rundeck.getExecution(execution.id);
    }

    echo 'RUNDECK EXECUTION OUTPUT'

    RundeckOutput rundeckOutput = rundeck.getJobExecutionOutput(execution.getId(), 0, 0, 0);
    if (null != rundeckOutput) {
        List<RundeckOutputEntry> logEntries = rundeckOutput.getLogEntries();
        if (null != logEntries) {
            String message = ""
            for (int i = 0; i < logEntries.size(); i++) {
                RundeckOutputEntry rundeckOutputEntry = (RundeckOutputEntry) logEntries.get(i);
                message += rundeckOutputEntry.message + "\n";
            }
            println message
        }
    }

    echo 'RUNDECK EXECUTION OUTPUT END'

    switch (execution.status) {
        case SUCCEEDED:
            println "Rundeck job ${execution.id} finished with success in ${execution.duration}"
            break;
        case FAILED:
            error 'Build failed!'
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

return this;
```

The relevant portion of my main script looks like this:

```
stage name: 'rundeck'
    node() {
        def externalRundeck = fileLoader.fromGit('jenkins-workflow-scripts/rundeck',
                '<git url>',
                'master',
                '<credentials>',
                '');

        rundeck.runJob('d919822e-c72e-4adc-b4cc-98ff7c9d5a5e', new Properties())
}
```

The output from the build is this:

```
[Pipeline] stage (rundeck)
Entering stage rundeck
Proceeding
[Pipeline] Allocate node : Start
Running on master in /home/jenkins/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/solrConfigWorklfow/workspace
[Pipeline] node {
[Pipeline] Allocate node : Start
Running on master in /home/jenkins/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/solrConfigWorklfow/workspace@2
[Pipeline] node {
[Pipeline] Change current directory : Start
Running in /home/jenkins/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/solrConfigWorklfow/workspace@2/libLoader
[Pipeline] dir {
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] echo
Checking out xxxxxxxxxxxx, branch=master
[Pipeline] git
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository xxxxxxxxxxx
 > git init /home/jenkins/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/solrConfigWorklfow/workspace@2/libLoader # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from xxxxxxxxxxxx
 > git --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > git config --local credential.username xxxxxxxxx # timeout=10
 > git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/git834036599103203072.credentials # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/viogate/dev-support.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url xxxxxxxx # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url xxxxxx # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from xxxxxxxxxx
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > git config --local credential.username xxxxxxxx # timeout=10
 > git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/git4826140835590679820.credentials # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/viogate/dev-support.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 522b47dc0761bde87b834966668b9458c6a5afd1 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 522b47dc0761bde87b834966668b9458c6a5afd1 # timeout=10
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b master 522b47dc0761bde87b834966668b9458c6a5afd1
[Pipeline] echo
Loading from jenkins-workflow-scripts/rundeck.groovy
[Pipeline] load (jenkins-workflow-scripts/rundeck.groovy)
[Pipeline] load {
[Pipeline] } //load
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] } //dir
[Pipeline] Change current directory : End
[Pipeline] } //node
[Pipeline] Allocate node : End
[Pipeline] } //node
[Pipeline] Allocate node : End
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: rundeck for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:62)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:221)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:23)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:24)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:62)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1552.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:106)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:164)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:277)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$000(CpsThreadGroup.java:77)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:184)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thanks for any tips!!

Comment: In your main script why do you load your lib into `externalRundeck` but after that use `rundeck` variable? Might this be the reason?

Comment: Stupid stupid me, can't believe I didn't spot that... :(